# MVC Security with the MvcMusicStore

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to work through the MVCMusicStore [TutoralPDF](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/downloads/get/228002) but chapters 6 and 7 have been a pain.

In chapter 7 I believed I followed all the directions

1. Added the Controller, Model, and Views to the project
2. Created an Administrator role through the ASP.net configuration
3. Created a user and added them the the Administrator role
4. Added the Authorize attribute to the StoreManager class

Now when I browse to /StoreManager I am redirected to a login.aspx page with a Return URl back to StoreManager instead of going to the Account controller, that is what I would expect to happen?

What did I do wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to add a forms tag to my authentication in the web config file.

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon"  />
  </authentication>
```

Otherwise the default in IIS and Virtual Server is login.aspx on a 302 error.